# EXCEL VBA: Editing a Column of Strings with a Function

Tags: excel, vba, string, function

I work with reports every day that list the results for each initiative we handle in a range of about 40 possible outcomes. I have created 4 groups which each of these outcomes could fall into to reduce the required comprehension, and would like my code to replace each individual outcome in column B with its assigned outcome group. This is my first time creating my own function in VBA, so please forgive any obvious errors.

I have created a simple Sub that should (hopefully) find the last row of column B, then loop up each row in the column passing the contained string to a function I've created. The should accept a string, perform a "select case" to ascertain which Outcome Group the string would be assigned to, then return the Outcome Group to the Sub for the current cell to be edited to. The select case options in my code have been reduced for readability. Additionally, the Function is stored in a separate VBA module to the sub.

```
Sub fixOutcomeColumn()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, col As Range
    Dim val As String

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    val = "test"
    Set col = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1" & lastRow)
    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1")

    For Each rng In col.Cells
        val = rng.Value
        rng = changeOutcomesToOG(val)
    Next rng

End Sub

Public Function changeOutcomesToOG(str As String) As String

    Select Case str
        Case "a"
            changeOutcomesToOG = "A"
        Case "b"
            changeOutcomesToOG = "B"
        Case "c"
            changeOutcomesToOG = "C"
        Case "d"
            changeOutcomesToOG = "D"
        Case "e"
            changeOutcomesToOG = "E"
        Case Else
            changeOutcomesToOG = str
    End Select

End Function
```

Stepping through the code in the editor while reading the Locals window shows me that my rng variable isn't being populated by any values when the code is run. Additionally, the code is not looping through each cell in the column, and runs the for loop once instead. I imagine I've made a pretty basic error, but can't figure it out for the life of me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
Sub fixOutcomeColumn()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, col As Range
    Dim val As String

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    val = "test"
    Set col = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
    'Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1")

    For Each rng In col.Cells
        val = rng.Value
        rng.Value = changeOutcomesToOG(val)
    Next rng

End Sub

Public Function changeOutcomesToOG(str As String) As String

    Select Case str
        Case "a"
            changeOutcomesToOG = "A"
        Case "b"
            changeOutcomesToOG = "B"
        Case "c"
            changeOutcomesToOG = "C"
        Case "d"
            changeOutcomesToOG = "D"
        Case "e"
            changeOutcomesToOG = "E"
        Case Else
            changeOutcomesToOG = str
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Try and find the line you are getting error on If any by using F8.

Comment: I can't believe one line ruined all the code! Thanks so much, this fixed it.

Comment: Well it's an answer now